# Two diagonals of a parallelogram $ABCD$ are $x+3y=4$ and $6x-2y=7$, then parallelogram represents

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> If two diagonals of a parallelogram $ABCD$ are along the lines $x+3y=4$ and $6x-2y=7$, then parallelogram represents
>   (a) rectangle
>   (b) rhombus
>   (c) square
>   (d) cyclic quadrilateral

$\bf{Attempts}$ with the help of slope

Slope of $x+3y=4$ is $\displaystyle m_{1} = -\frac{1}{3}$ and slope of $6x-2y=7$ is $\displaystyle m_{2} = -\frac{6}{-2} = 3$

So we have $m_{1}\cdot m_{2} = -1$ . So parallelogram represent Rhombus and Square.

But answer given is only Rhombus, could someone explain me the reason, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The two diagonals of the parallelogram being perpendicular to each other only defines a rhombus, not a square in particular. A square is a special case of a rhombus, with equal angles.

Comment: a square is also a parallelogram, but a Rhombus must not be a square

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Trite, whaddya know? A rhombus _may_ be a square.

Comment: Thanks Parcly Taxel, can we say that option $(c)$ is also true.

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari No. Just scale the points on one diagonal evenly from the centre and you have a non-square rhombus.

Comment: Parcly Taxel I did not understand the meaning of that line

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari By that I mean you can draw non-square rhombuses with the given diagonals, so (c) is not true in all cases.

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari In other words, there’s not enough information given to say for sure that it’s a square.